# WebSocket connection failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, java-websocket

I have checked a lot of answers but unable to solve this issue.Anyone can help me to resolve this issue using java websocket.

> ChatEndPoint.Java

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/chat/{username}", decoders = MessageDecoder.class, encoders =MessageEncoder.class)
public class ChatEndPoint {

    private Session session;
    private static final Set<ChatEndPoint> chatEndpoints = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<ChatEndPoint>();
    private static HashMap<String, String> users = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam("username") String username) throws IOException, EncodeException {
         System.out.println("connected");
        this.session = session;
        chatEndpoints.add(this);
        users.put(session.getId(), username);

        Message message = new Message();
        message.setFrom(username);
        message.setContent("Connected!");
        broadcast(message);
    }

    @OnMessage 
    public void onMessage(Session session, Message message) throws IOException, EncodeException {
        message.setFrom(users.get(session.getId()));
        broadcast(message);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) throws IOException, EncodeException {
        chatEndpoints.remove(this);
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setFrom(users.get(session.getId()));
        message.setContent("Disconnected!");
        broadcast(message);
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable throwable) {
        // Do error handling here
        System.out.println(session.getId());
    }

    private static void broadcast(Message message) throws IOException, EncodeException {
        chatEndpoints.forEach(endpoint -> {
            synchronized (endpoint) {
                try {
                    endpoint.session.getBasicRemote()
                        .sendObject(message);
                } 

                catch (IOException | EncodeException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

}
```

> websocket.js

```
var ws;

function connect() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;

    var host = document.location.host;
    var pathname = document.location.pathname;

    ws = new WebSocket("ws://"+host+"/chat/" + username);

    ws.onmessage = function(event) {
    var log = document.getElementById("log");
        console.log(event.data);
        var message = JSON.parse(event.data);
        log.innerHTML += message.from + " : " + message.content + "\n";
    };
}

function send() {
    var content = document.getElementById("msg").value;
    var json = JSON.stringify({
        "content":content
    });

    ws.send(json);
}
```

> index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username"/>
                    <button type="button" onclick="connect();" >Connect</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea readonly="true" rows="10" cols="80" id="log"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" size="51" id="msg" placeholder="Message"/>
                    <button type="button" onclick="send();" >Send</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

    <script src="js/websocket.js"></script>

</html>
```

> Using maven and dependencies are :

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
       <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
       <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

Using apache tomcat 8.0 and java 8.0. I have wasted almost two days .Please any help me .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend including more information about the error message and stack trace in your question.

Comment: If you get me your mail id i can share my demo project.

Comment: I'm probably not going to be able to get you to an answer alone. If there's sensitive info the the stacktrace, blank it out. But it is going to be important to know if the error is happening in the Java or the JS, as well as what line in the relevant file.